# Where to store your Service API URL

Tags: angular

I have a separate WebApi project and an Angular 8 application. My angular application is making calls to the WebApi to retrieve the data. Is there a best practice to store your WebApi URI within your angular application? Would it just a variable within each Service component? Is it a variable within appsettings.json file? Currently I have it within my service components but this is a pain when changing between local, dev, qa and staging environments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a good practice. Simply store it in env/environment.ts.